# How to display a message on top?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, apple-watch

I'm new to WatchKit development. I would like to display a message regardless of what app is currently being used or whether the watch is active or not, like how the built-in Timer app shows the label "Timer Done". The user should then be able to click an "OK" button and dismiss the message.

I have tried using both alerts and modal views, but showing them programmatically still requires my app to be active. Using the notifications system is not a viable solution because that would rely on an iPhone.

I've been stuck on this for many hours, any insight would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: You can post local notifications from your watch app in WatchOS 3.0 but not in WatchOS2.0 https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask permission in your iOS App first:

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.badge,.sound])
    { (granted, error) in
        if !granted
        {
            print("User did not give permissions to send notitications...")
        }
    }
```

Then in your watchOS App you can create a notification for some time in the future, make sure you give it a UUID (this may be a bug in watchOS3):

```
    let content: UNMutableNotificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "Title"

    content.subtitle = "Subtitle"

    content.body = "message"

    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    content.categoryIdentifier = "aCategory"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: duration, repeats: false)

    let id: String = WatchNotify.getUUID()
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: id,
                                        content: content,
                                        trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    {
        (error) in // ...
    }
```

....

```
class func getUUID() -> String
{
    let uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
    let uuidString = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj)!
    return uuidString as String
}
```